# Bitbucket Failed to persist entry: API_ERROR: Branch not found

Tags: bitbucket, netlify, netlify-cms

The website is built using Gatsby with Netlify CMS in Bitbucket. The error shows when I tried to change something on the custom page using the Netlify CMS (Live), but works perfectly on the local setup. This confuses me and I don't know what and why is that happening.

Here's my config.yml

```
backend:
  name: bitbucket
  repo: repo-name
  branch: master
  auth_type: implicit
  app_id: app-id
  commit_messages:
    create: "Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”"
    update: "Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”"
    delete: "Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”"
    uploadMedia: "[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”"
    deleteMedia: "[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”"

local_backend: true
publish_mode: editorial_workflow
media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
```

(Skipped some because it is too long but here is the setup of the custom page)

```
- name: "pages"
    label: "Pages"
    label_singular: "Page"
    create: true
    files:
  - file: "src/pages/resources/i-mop-xl-operator-resources.md"
    label: "i-mop xl operator resources"
    name: "i-mop xl operator resources"
    fields:
      - {
          label: "Template Key",
          name: "templateKey",
          widget: "hidden",
          default: "i-mop-xl-operator-resources",
        }
      - { label: Title, name: title, widget: string }
      - { label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string }
      - { label: Description, name: description, widget: string }
      - {
          label: "Seo Description",
          name: "seodescription",
          widget: "string",
        }
      - { label: "Seo Keyword", name: "seokeyword", widget: "string" }
      - {
          label: "Seo Title",
          name: "seotitle",
          widget: "string",
          required: false,
        }
```

And the error is saying

[image]

P.S this is only happening on the new pages that I've created.

Comment: Have you tried using `name: git-gateway` instead of `bitbucket`?

Comment: I mean this project is in bitbucket. And it works perfectly on the other pages. Seems that this custom page is the one that is getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the solution to this and I think it is pretty simple. The name should not have a blank space.
From this:

```
- file: "src/pages/resources/i-mop-xl-operator-resources.md"
  label: "i-mop xl operator resources"
  name: "i-mop xl operator resources"
```

To this:

```
- file: "src/pages/resources/i-mop-xl-operator-resources.md"
  label: "i-mop xl operator resources"
  name: "i-mop-xl-operator-resources"
```